# Completion of a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Consider the ring $$R= \mathbb{Z}_p[x,y]/((x^2-2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)+p^ry),$$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $r$ is an integer greater than $1$. I want to show that the completion of $R$ at $(p,x,y)$ is isomorphic to the completion of a ring of the form $$\mathbb{Z}_p[x,y]/(xy-v)$$ at the origin, where $v \in (p) \cap \mathbb{Z}_p$. I don't seem to be able to work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion is equal to $\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]/((2-x^2 -y^2)(x^2 - y^2)-p^ry)$. Now the element $2 -x^2 -y^2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]$, since it has an invertible constant terms, and so we can rewrite this as $$\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]/(x^2 - y^2 - u),$$ where $u = (2 - x^2 - y^2)^{-1}p^r y.$

Now if we write $s = x-y, t = x+y,$ then $\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]] = \mathbb Z_p[[s,t]]$ (again using that $p$ is odd to inert the relationship between $(s,t)$ and $(x,y)$), and hence we may rewrite the completion as
$$\mathbb Z_p[[s,t]](st - v),$$ which is the required form.

Added: As YACP alludes to in a comment, the element $v$ is a multiple of $p$, but does not lie in $\mathbb Z_p$.  However, I don't think it's possible to achieve this last condition (although I don't have time now to check it carefully).

Comment: Is $v \in (p) \cap \mathbb{Z}_p$? (Btw, what means $\mathbb Z_p$ here?)

Comment: @YACP: Dear YACP, $v$ is a multiple of $p$, but you're right that it's not in $\mathbb Z_p$; I didn't pay attention to that requirement.  And I took $\mathbb Z_p$ to mean the $p$-adic integers; what else might it mean?  Regards,